# Extract 1st word of blogname/insert in middle of new string

Tags: php

Wordpress Website Name (say) = "German Philosophy Politics & Economics"

I want to return "My German Site"

I have tried the following :

```
<?php
$myvalue = bloginfo('name');
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
$var = $arr[0];
echo "My ".$var." Site";
?>
```

but it returns "German My Site"

not "My German Site"

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

if in doubt, read the codex chapter for the function you are working with: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo 
which points to the use of [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) if you need to use the value in php string manipulations.